# Backbone-relational fetchRelated not sending request

Tags: backbone.js, fetch, backbone-relational

I'm using backbone.js  and backbone relational 0.5.0 with a Rails 3.2 backend. I have a Card model which has_many Notes.

Here are my JS models and collections:

```
Workflow.Collections.Cards = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
  model: Workflow.Models.Card,
  url: '/cards'
});

Workflow.Models.Card = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  modelName   : 'card',
  urlRoot     : '/cards',

  relations: [
  {
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'notes',
    relatedModel: 'Workflow.Models.Note',
    collectionType: 'Workflow.Collections.Notes',
    includeInJSON: false,
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'card',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    }
  }]

});

Workflow.Collections.Notes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Workflow.Models.Note,
  url: '/cards/74/notes' // intentionally hard-coded for now
});

Workflow.Models.Note = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  modelName   : 'note',
  urlRoot     : '/notes'
});
```

Normal fetching works great, but when I try fetchRelated in the console, I get an empty array:

```
card = new Workflow.Models.Card({id: 74}) // cool
card.fetch() // hits the sever with GET "/cards/74" - works great
card.fetchRelated('notes') // [] - didn't even try to hit the server
```

What's weird is that this works:

```
card.get('notes').fetch() // cool - GET "/cards/74/notes"
```

I *could* use that method and parse the response text, but it feels really dirty.

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance, this one is really torturing me!

Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have posted my solution a while back - there might well be a better way, but this is the convention I've gone with:

All of the following code is in the **card view** (which is where the notes are displayed).

First, I bind a `renderNotes` method to the `'reset'` event on the card's notes collection:

```
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);

    this.model.get('notes').on('reset', this.renderNotes);

    var self = this;
    this.model.get('notes').on('add', function(addedNote, relatedCollection) {
      self.renderNote(addedNote);
    });
  }
```

I also bind to the `'add'` on that collection to call a singular `renderNote`.

The renderNotes and renderNote methods work like this:

```
renderNotes: function () {
    if (this.model.get('notes')) {
      this.model.get('notes').each(this.renderNote);
    }
  },

  renderNote: function (note) {
    var noteView = new Workflow.Views.Note({ model: note });
    this.$('.notes').append(noteView.render().el);
  },
```

Then, the last piece of the puzzle is to actually hit the server up for the card's notes (which will in turn fire the `'reset'` event I bound to above). I do this in the card view's `render` method:

```
render: function () {
    // render all of the eager-loaded things
    this.model.get('notes').fetch();
    return this;
  },
```

As @user1248256 kindly helped me work out in the comments on my OP, the confusion was mainly in that I expected `fetchRelated` to pull down lazy-loaded records - that's actually not the case.

As a side-note, this view is actually a modal and be opened and closed (removed from the page). To prevent the zombie events problem described in [this excellent post](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/&ei=Up8EULXmBe7omAXmm_2kBg&usg=AFQjCNEP8_EpNm9a5ygpvsRfviq-izWdIA&sig2=xXQ3eYohyrSSZ0rrhYz8jQ), I also manually unbind the events mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You should create `Card` with `Note` ids array: `card = new Workflow.Models.Card({id: 74, notes: [74, 75]});` and change the `url` method of `Notes` accordingly:

```
Workflow.Collections.Notes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Workflow.Models.Note
});

Workflow.Models.Note = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  modelName   : 'note',
  urlRoot     : function () {
    return this.get('card').url() + '/notes';
}
});

card = new Workflow.Models.Card({id: 74, notes: [74, 75]});
card.fetchRelated('notes');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theotheo/5DAzx/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get to my computer! Can i ask what purpose giving the card some notes to begin with serves? I'm trying to lazy-load this data instead of bringing it down when the page loads and I bootstrap the cards etc so most likely my card JS models will not be aware of their notes before I fetch them...

Comment: Okay, progress. That fires off a GET for each note we specified. Any idea if I can use fetchRelated to completely lazy-load the notes? I want to pull down new ones from the server...

Comment: Okay, I take your point. I've took a peek at the backbone-relational source and I think you cannot use `fetchRelated` without a corresponding model ids array. Btw, you could take a look at the [unit tests][1] for examples of usage `fetchRelated`. 
So, you could get `Note` ids array when you fetch a `Card` and then call `fetchRelated`. Or maybe you wouldn't like to do this?
[1]: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/blob/master/test/tests.js#L563

Comment: Good point with the unit tests, I'll have a look. I suppose I could either change my API to have a slimmer version of the cards bootstrapped with only an id for each note and then lazy load when required. My main concern would still be notes that are added in the interim period. I have been reading some more docs and I reckon I can specify a prase() method on the notes collection to make sure that calling card.get('notes').fetch() will populate a collection of all of the notes for a card without knowing the IDs in advance. Once I have it tweaked I'll post the solution. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You could also override the `fetchRelated()` of `card` to first `fetch()` the collection and then call the parent's `fetchRelated()`. I haven't tried this approach yet, but I'm considering it since I, too, would like to lazy load even the IDs to reduce unnecessary load on the DB.

Comment: this is old but it really helped me, thanks for the fiddle I didn't get it until I plugged in my own collection and model and it all made sense... This should have been the answer...